# Start at Row A19 instead of Row A1

Tags: excel, vba, row, userform, data-entry

I am trying to have an entry data userform where the input starts at "A19" and will end at row "A30" once the empty rows get filled 1 by 1, instead of the current situation where it starts at "A1" and goes unrestricted.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Set wks = ActiveSheet

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A2:A65565").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(0, 2).Value = txtCAC.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 4).Value = txtName.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 5).Value = txtType.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 6).Value = txtClass.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 7).Value = txtDate.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 8).Value = txtParent.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 9).Value = txtManagement.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 10).Value = txtSuccess.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 12).Value = txtPercentage.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 21).Value = txtCommittment.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 38).Value = txtContribution.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 40).Value = txtRedemption.Text

lstDisplay.ColumnCount = 41
lstDisplay.RowSource = "A2:A65356"

End Sub
```

Comment: let me know if you need other information! I appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Is there any data already in column A when doing the Set AddNew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As apparently your goal is to overwrite an adjacent fixed target range
with a complete set of textbox entries, I'd propose the following steps:

- `[0.]` Define the fixed start cell in target cell e.g. via `set tgt = Sheet1.Range("A19")`.
- `[1. a)]` `Split` a list of needed textbox names thus getting a 1-dimensional array, which btw will be 0-based automatically.
- `[1. b)]` Provide for data by a 2-dim data array and make it zero-based, too in order to
  synchronize both array counters in the following loop (1.c).
- `[1. c)]` Fill the data array rows with all textbox contents by a `For`..`Next` loop
  and check for not allowed zero-length inputs;
  if there are any display a warning message and redirect focus to the empty textbox.
- `[2.]` Eventually dump back the data array to the chosen target range
  by using the number of listed textbox controls `cnt` to `.Resize` the target range (e.g. 12 in OP).

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

'0. Define fixed start cell in target range
    dim tgt as Range
    set tgt = Sheet1.Range("A19")                ' change to any wanted sheet Code(Name)
'1. a) split a list of needed textbox names getting a 1-dim 0-based array automatically
    Dim myTextboxes As Variant
    myTextboxes = Split( _
        "txtCAC,txtName,txtType,txtClass,txtDate,txtParent,txtManagement," & _
        "txtSuccess,txtPercentage,txtCommittment,txtContribution,TxtRedemption", _
        ",")
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = UBound(myTextboxes) + 1                ' count number of textboxes

'   b) provide for data by a 2-dim data array (make it zero-based, too)
    Dim data As Variant
    ReDim data(0 To cnt - 1, 0 To 0)             ' define dimensions holding data

'   c) fill data array rows with all textbox contents
    Dim i As Long, ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data)         ' i.e. 0 To 11
        Set ctrl = Me.Controls(myTextboxes(i))   ' set control to memory
        data(i, 0) = ctrl.Text                   ' get textbox content
        
    ' check for complete entries or exit sub
        If Len(Trim(data(i, 0))) = 0 Then        ' check for zero-length input
            MsgBox "Fill in empty Textbox(es) first!", vbExclamation, ctrl.Name
            ctrl.SetFocus                        ' set focus to empty box
            Exit Sub                             ' escape procedure
        End If
    Next

'2. dump data to target range               
    tgt.Resize(cnt, 1) = data             ' write data

End Sub
```

*Further hints*

I think there will be to need to define a RowSource (btw better to use `"Sheet1!A19:A30"` if you are overwriting all data anyway by command button.

Side note: Prefer to get a last row cell via e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` or the row index via `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` instead of coding a fixed rows count (current sheets have at about 1 million). You might be interested in reading [Finding last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920)
`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim AddNew As Range
Set wks = ActiveSheet
Dim h As Integer

h = wks.Range("C65356").End(xlUp).Row

If h < 18 Then h = 18
if h > 30 then exit Sub

Set AddNew = wks.Range("A" & h)

AddNew.Offset(1, 2).Value = txtCAC.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 4).Value = txtName.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 5).Value = txtType.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 6).Value = txtClass.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 7).Value = txtDate.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 8).Value = txtParent.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 9).Value = txtManagement.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 10).Value = txtSuccess.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 12).Value = txtPercentage.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 21).Value = txtCommittment.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 38).Value = txtContribution.Text
AddNew.Offset(1, 40).Value = txtRedemption.Text

'lstDisplay.ColumnCount = 41
'lstDisplay.RowSource = "A2:A65356"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).